# bluemix app push hangs after upload

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

command **bx app push** hangs after message "*Done uploading*" is shown.
I activated CF_TRACE env var, and the following request is made several times before failing with:

**Error processing app files: Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 0, message:**

```
    REQUEST: [2018-08-01T11:47:21-03:00]
    GET /v2/jobs/5dc92acb-8573-422b-8a60-2e6b558dc26e HTTP/1.1
    Host: api.ng.bluemix.net
    Accept: application/json
    Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: application/json
    User-Agent: go-cli 6.32.0+0191c33d9.2017-09-26 / linux



    RESPONSE: [2018-08-01T11:47:21-03:00]
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 270
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 14:47:21 GMT
    Expires: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 14:47:21 GMT
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: nginx
    X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Global-Transaction-Id: 2574851421

    {
      "metadata": {
        "guid": "5dc92acb-8573-422b-8a60-2e6b558dc26e",
        "created_at": "2018-08-01T14:36:25Z",
        "url": "/v2/jobs/5dc92acb-8573-422b-8a60-2e6b558dc26e"
      },
      "entity": {
        "guid": "5dc92acb-8573-422b-8a60-2e6b558dc26e",
        "status": "queued"
      }
    }
```

I noticed the status queued on the entity object. What that means ? What can I do?

EDIT:
There was a problem with the region my app was on. It was reported at: https://console.bluemix.net/status

Comment: If you are in US South, there is currently an issue. https://console.bluemix.net/status/notification/6dd358bed1992458971f034ab9b7159a

Comment: Yeah... just noticed that, on the very same link. Thanks! I'll just edit refering the link for future reference.